# Comparing marginal on product space with other measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

My previous post [Unifying the treatment of discrete and continuous random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058621/unifying-the-treatment-of-discrete-and-continuous-random-variable), got successfully answered and allowed me to get further in my results. However I am facing a question that I can't seems to answer... So here it is :

Let $(\Omega_i, \sigma(\Omega_i), P_i) \; \forall i=0,1$ be two measure space.

Let $(\Omega_0 \times\Omega_1, \sigma(\Omega_0)\otimes\sigma(\Omega_1), \lambda)$ be the product measure space.

Following the answer to my previous post, if the spaces $\Omega_i$ are nice enough :
\begin{align}
\exists\; p_x: \sigma(\Omega_1)\longmapsto [0,1]
\end{align}
Such as $p_x$ is a measure $\forall \;x \in \Omega_0$, and is measurable $\forall\; B\in \sigma(\Omega_1)$, and :
\begin{align}
\lambda(A\times B)= \int_Ap_x(B)dP_X
\end{align}
Where $P_X(A) = \lambda(A\times\Omega_1)$.

I was wondering how does $P_X$ and $P_0$ compare? They are both measure on the same space. Is it required by construction of the product measure that $P_X=P_0$ ?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: To declare that the product is "the product measure space" is to declare that $\lambda=P_0\otimes P_1$ then indeed $P_X=P_0$ and $p_x=P_1$ for every $x$ in $\Omega_0$, **by definition**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mess up a couple of notions here. It certainly depends on which question are you dealing with more often, but I think it would be rather common to deal with a fixed *measurable* space, and consider *several* measures on it. That is, try to think of measurable spaces unless you really need to start using measures already.

To make abstract insinuations above a bit more clear, let's consider your particular example. If you have measurable spaces $(\Omega_i,\mathcal F_i)$, their product is again a *measurable* space 
$$
  (\Omega,\mathcal F) = \left(\prod_i \Omega_i,\bigotimes_i \mathcal F_i\right).
$$
Any measure $\lambda$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ factors as marginal distributions $\lambda_i$, conditional distribution etc. over the product structure. Note that for that we did not have to define any measures on $\Omega_i$ in advance.

Alternatively, we can start with *measure* spaces $(\Omega_i,\mathcal F_i, P_i)$. Then their product is a measure space itself, given by $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ where $P = \bigotimes_i P_i$ is the product measure, which corresponds to independent random variables in case of probability measure, hence to trivial conditional distributions. In that case, $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ already comes endowed with the fixed product measure, which is determined by measures $P_i$ defined over its factor spaces.

Summarizing the information above, you can answer your question is follows. The measures $P_i$ and $P_X$ (or $\lambda)$ in your notation are not related at all. When you define the product measurable space, you don't use $P_i$, and then you endow it with measure $\lambda$ which is taken out of the sky, hence no relation again. There is a subtle detail regarding whether you define a product measure space to be complete (in which case $\lambda$ must be defined over a bigger $\sigma$-algebra), but I don't think that's your matter here.

Comment: I should have known you would answer this one too :). If I understood correctly, the two measures $P_X$ and $P_0$ have no relation whatsoever unless $\lambda$ has been constructed using $P_i$. Int this last case, $P_X = P_0$ and correspond to the marginal of $\lambda$ on the space $\Omega_0$. The completion part is understood I think.

Comment: @user149705: yes, indeed

Comment: Thank you for the quality of your answers. It is surely greatly appreciated by me and others.