# Expectation of a discrete random variable: how to convert an integral to a sum?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, expectation

According to wikipedia and all my textbooks, we define the expectation of a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ :
\begin{align}
E(X) &= \int_{\Omega}XdP\\
\end{align}

This is no matter if the random variable is discrete, continuous or neither. What I would like to know is how to derive the basic formulas :
\begin{align}
E(X) &= \sum_i \omega_ip(\omega_i)\\
E(X) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} xp(x)d\lambda\\
\end{align}

For the discrete and continuous case. Please note that I got the derivation of the continuous case already figured out. I am trying to do the same for the discrete one. So I define the distribution of $X$ like so $PX^{-1}(A) = \sum_i a_i\mathbb{1}_A(a_i)$ because the distribution is finite valued. Now plugin everything together I get stuck with an integral I don't know how to solve. None of my textbooks provide a derivation like this and switch directly from integral to sums.

---

I am sorry that my question wasn't very clear, this is my 2nd attempt to explain it.

Comment: One cannot solve the case of continuous distributions by writing them as discrete ones, but it seems this is what you are doing. Please explain.

Comment: Oh sure ! I am trying to derive all my results starting from a common definition. Starting from $E(X)=\int_{\Omega}XdP$, I want to go as far as I need and then switch to the hypotheses regarding the distribution I consider. The first derivation looks correct ( or not ? ). The second derivation actually is inspired by the continuous case where $PX^{-1} << \lambda$ we end up with $E(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}xf(x)dx$ where $f$ is the density of $PX^{-1}$. A similar treatment is used here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058621/unifying-the-treatment-of-discrete-and-continuous-random-variable

Comment: Rather, a similarly ill-defined approach is exposed there and refuted by the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? I don't really understand what is ill -defined here. The definition of the discrete distribution seems fine. The definition of the integral looks fine too since it is an integral w.r.t to a measure and X is by definition measurable. Thank you !

Comment: As you say, $E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X\mathrm{d}P$. We know that, if $\mu_X$ is the [pushforward measure](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) pushed onto $\mathbb{R}$ by $X$, that we can equivalently define $E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathrm{d}\mu_X$. So now we only need to prove that if $X$ is discrete with density $p_X$, then for any function we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu_X=\sum f(x)p_X(x)$. We start by indicators. The integral, when $f=\mathbb{1}_{B}$, reduces to $\mu_X(B)$. But by definition of discrete probability, $\mu_X(B)=\sum_{x\in B}p_X(x)$. And since $\mathbb{1}_B$ is …

Comment: 1 on $B$ and 0 out of it, the sum $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$ is precisely $\sum_{x\in B}p_X(x)$. In this case, we have the desired equality. Next step: simple functions. If $f=\sum a_i\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$, a finite sum of multiples of indicators, by linearity of the integral we have that the LHS of our desired equality is $\sum a_i\int\mathbb{1}_{A_i}\mathrm{d}\mu_X$, which is, by the result above, $\sum a_i(\sum_{x\in A_i}p_X(x))$, which you can easily see to match $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$. Next step: positive functions. If $f\geq0$, we know it can be approximated monotonely by simple functions. The limit …

Comment: passes under the integral by the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem). If the sum on the RHS is finite, we can easily pass the limit under the sum. If it is infinite, let's write it. We know $f_n\uparrow f$. THe sum is $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$, and we want it to equal $\lim\sum f_n(x)p_X(x)$. So we need to prove $\lim_n\sum_{x\in\Omega}f_n(x)p_X(x)=\sum_{x\in\Omega}\lim_nf_n(x)p_X(x)$. Now, the sum is defined as the supremum of finite subsums. For each finite subsum the equality holds.

Comment: So for any $S\subseteq\Omega$ with $S$ finite, we have $\lim_n\sum_{x\in S}f_n(x)p_X(x)=\sum_{x\in S}\lim_nf_n(x)p_X(x)$. The sup of the RHS is the RHS above. Can we justify the swapping of sup and limit? Suppose we have $s_{n,k}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in I$ with $I$ any index set. We want to compare $\lim_n\sup_ks_{n,k}$ and $\sup_k\lim_ns_{n,k}$. The sup of the limit is greater than any limit. Therefore it is greater than any $s_{n,k}$. Therefore it is greater than any sup, implying it is greater than the limit of the sup. So $\sup\lim\geq\lim\sup$. The sequences we are actually …

Comment: working with are monotonic increasing in $n$, so $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k,n$. Therefore the sequence of the sups is also monotone, so the limit of the sups is greater than all of the sups, so greater than all $s_{n,k}$, so greater than any $\lim_ns_{n,k}$, and so also of their sup. This proves the other inequality, giving us the desired equality. That was the hardest part. For generic functions, remember that an infinite sum is defined as the sum of the positive parts minus that of the negative parts, where those are defined as with positive functions, i.e. as the above sup. …

Comment: But for positive and negative part, we have proved the equality. So we have the equality for generic functions. IN summary, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathrm{d}\mu_X(x)=\sum xp_X(x)$, actually even more generally for any measurable function $f$ we have $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu_X(x)=\sum f(x)p_X(x)$. DOes that answer you? If so, I wish I could post it as an answer, but the question is on hold and answers are blocked.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful answer. As much as I like your proof, I would still like to know how to derive the result without trying to prove it. The push-forward measure you define should be the distribution of X ($PX^{-1}$). The problem here is that I don't know how to deal with this kind of integral (a.k.a $\int_{\mathbb{R}} xd(\sum_i p(\omega_i)\mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(\omega_i))$. Basically how to derive the result consisting of the sum starting from this. The integral seems weel defined since the push-forward measure is a measure. Hopefully I am being clear ...

Comment: Side note: *well, not "weel" :). Anyway, see my answer below. Luckily the post has been put back off hold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand{\one}{\mathbb{1}}$
Reposting my comments as an answer, and adding another way of proving the same.

**Mathematical proof**

As you say, $E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X\mathrm{d}P$. We know that, if $\mu_X$ is the pushforward measure pushed onto $\mathbb{R}$ by $X$, that we can equivalently define $E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathrm{d}\mu_X$. So now we only need to prove that if $X$ is discrete with density $p_X$, then for any function we have:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu_X=\sum_{x\in\Omega}f(x)p_X(x).$$

We start from indicators. The integral, when $f=\mathbb{1}_B$, reduces to $\mu_X(B)$. But by definition of discrete probability, $\mu_X(B)=\sum_{x\in B}p_X(x)$. And since $\mathbb{1}_B$ is 1 on $B$ and 0 out of it, the sum $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$ is precisely $\sum_{x\in B}p_X(x)$. In this case, we have the desired equality.

Next step: simple functions. If $f=\sum a_i\one_{A_i}$, a finite sum of multiples of indicators, by linearity of the integral we have that the LHS of our desired equality is $\sum a_i\int\one_{A_i}\mathrm{d}\mu_X$, which is, by the result above, $\sum a_i(\sum_{x\in A_i}p_X(x))$, which you can easily see to match $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$.

Next step: positive functions. If $f\geq0$, we know it can be approximated monotonely by simple functions. The limit passes under the integral by the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem). If the sum on the RHS is finite, we can easily pass the limit under the sum. If it is infinite, let's write it. We know $f_n\uparrow f$. The sum is $\sum f(x)p_X(x)$, and we want it to equal $\lim\sum f_n(x)p_X(x)$. So we need to prove that:
$$\lim_n\sum_{x\in\Omega}f_n(x)p_X(x)=\sum_{x\in\Omega}\lim_nf_n(x)p_X(x).$$
Now, the sum is defined as the supremum of finite subsums. For each finite subsum the equality holds. So for any $S\subseteq\Omega$ with $S$ finite, we have:
$$\lim_n\sum_{x\in S}f_n(x)p_X(x)=\sum_{x\in S}\lim_nf_n(x)pX(x).$$
The sup of the RHS is the RHS above. Can we justify the swapping of sup and limit? Suppose we have $s_{n,k}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N},k\in I$ with $I$ any index set. We want to compare $lim_n\sup_ks_{n,k}$ and $sup_k\lim_ns_{n,k}$. The sup of the limits is greater than any limit. Therefore it is greater than any $s_{n,k}$. Therefore it is greater than any sup, implying it is greater than the limit of the sups. So $\sup\lim\geq\lim\sup$. The sequences we are actually working with are monotonic increasing in $n$, so $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k,n$ (maybe I should say monotonic *non-decreasing* rather than *increasing*; details :) ). Therefore the sequence of the sups is also monotone, so the limit of the sups is greater than all of the sups, so greater than all $s_{n,k}$, so greater than any $\lim_ns_{n,k}$, and so also of their sup. This proves the other inequality, giving us the desired equality. That was the hardest part.

For generic functions, remember that an infinite sum is defined as the sum of the positive parts minus that of the negative parts, where those are defined as with positive functions, i.e. as the above sup. But for positive and negative part, we have proved the equality. So we have the equality for generic functions.

In summary:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\mathrm{d}\mu_X(x)=\sum_{x\in\Omega}xp_X(x),$$
actually even more generally for any measurable function $f$ we have:
$$\int f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu_X(x)=\sum f(x)p_X(x).$$

---

**Bonus**

By the way, from the reasoning above you can extract the following lemma.

**Lemma**

If $s_{n,k}$ are real numbers for which $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\in I$ with $I$ a generic set of indices, $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k\in I$, then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\in I}s_{n,k}=\sup_{k\in I}\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n,k}.$$

**Proof**

> We want to compare $lim_n\sup_ks_{n,k}$ and $sup_k\lim_ns_{n,k}$. The sup of the limits is greater than any limit. Therefore it is greater than any $s_{n,k}$. Therefore it is greater than any sup, implying it is greater than the limit of the sups. So:
>   $$(1)\qquad \sup\lim\geq\lim\sup.$$
>   The sequences $(s_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we are working with are monotonic nondecreasing in $n$, so $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k,n$. Therefore the sequence of the sups is also monotone, so the limit of the sups is greater than all of the sups, so greater than all $s_{n,k}$, so greater than any $\lim_ns_{n,k}$, and so also of their sup. This proves the other inequality:
>   $$(2)\qquad \lim\sup\geq\sup\lim.$$
>   By combining (1) and (2), we get the lemma.

By a similar argument, one can probably deduce the inf swaps with the limits in case of non-*increasing* monotonicity ($s_{n,k}\geq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k\in I,n\in\mathbb{N}$).

---

**Formal derivation**

If by *derive it* you mean *get to it without a proof*, well, we can always assume that if $\mu_i$ are measures, then:
$$\mathrm{d}(\sum a_i\mu_i)=\sum a_i\mathrm{d}\mu_i. \tag{$\ast$}$$
Your expression of $PX^{-1}$ doesn't really make sense, since it is not a measure but a sum of multiples of indicators. Now a discreet random variable takes a finite or numerable set of values with probability 1. If $A$ is a set in the $\sigma$-algebra of the target space of the variable (typically, a Borel set in the reals), the distribution $\mu_X(A)$ can, by $\sigma$-additivity of measures, be written as:
$$\mu_X(A)=\sum_{x\in A\cap V}p(x),$$
$V$ being the above countable set. That is the same value as $\sum_{x\in V}p(x)\delta_{x}(A)$, $\delta$ representing the Dirac delta measure. So we have seen that:
$$\mu_X=\sum_Vp(x)\delta_{x}.$$
Going back to the expectation, we know that:
$$E[X]=\int_{\Omega}X\mathrm{d}P=\int_{\mathbb{R}}t\mathrm{d}\mu_X(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}t\mathrm{d}\left(\sum_Vp(x)\delta_x(t)\right).$$
Assuming $\ast$ above, we continue the equality chain:
$$E[X]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}t\sum_Vp(x)\mathrm{d}\delta_x(t).$$
We can also assume the integral and sum can be harmlessly swapped. This then becomes a sum of integrals, and integrating something with respect to a delta gives the value of that something at the center of the delta, i.e. $\int f(t)\mathrm{d}\delta_x(t)=f(x)$, so:
$$E[X]=\sum_V\int_{\mathbb{R}}tp(x)\mathrm{d}\delta_x(t)=\sum_Vxp(x),$$
the desired result.

Comment: Awesome answer. Exactly what I was looking for. I was precisely stuck on the last equation. You made it appear really simple and clear. Thank you !

Comment: Just to make something clear, you say that $PX^{-1}$ doesn't make sense but I think it is the same definition as your $\mu_X$ since $\mathbb{1}_A(x) = \delta_x(A)$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Notationally, it doesn't make sense. So it should be expressed as I did. Your equality holds, I hadn't realized that. So yes, it is just a notational issue, your definition and mine are the same thing :).

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification !

Comment: To expand on that, since you are expressing a measure $\mu_X$, you want to have the set as the argument, hence the choice of the delta, not to have the set as an index while the argument is a point which doesn't depend on the set, as happens with an indicator. That is why expressing the distribution with the delta is notationally better. And you're welcome @user149705.