# Two lemmas: ever proved? Name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**Lemma**

If $s_{n,k}$ are real numbers for which $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\in I$ with $I$ a generic set of indices, $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k\in I$, then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\in I}s_{n,k}=\sup_{k\in I}\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n,k}.$$

**Proof**

> We want to compare $\lim_n\sup_ks_{n,k}$ and $\sup_k\lim_ns_{n,k}$. The sup of the limits is greater than any limit. Therefore it is greater than any $s_{n,k}$. Therefore it is greater than any sup, implying it is greater than the limit of the sups. So:
>   $$(1)\qquad \sup\lim\geq\lim\sup.$$
>   The sequences $(s_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ we are working with are monotonic nondecreasing in $n$, so $s_{n,k}\leq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k,n$. Therefore the sequence of the sups is also monotone, so the limit of the sups is greater than all of the sups, so greater than all $s_{n,k}$, so greater than any $\lim_ns_{n,k}$, and so also of their sup. This proves the other inequality:
>   $$(2)\qquad \lim\sup\geq\sup\lim.$$
>   By combining (1) and (2), we get the lemma.

---

By a similar argument, one can probably deduce the inf swaps with the limits in case of non-*increasing* monotonicity ($s_{n,k}\geq s_{n+1,k}$ for all $k\in I,n\in\mathbb{N}$).

---

I came up with these (the lemma with proof and the isolated sentence above) in my study of Measure Theory, and this is an extract of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082240/expectation-of-a-discrete-random-variable-how-to-convert-an-integral-to-a-sum). Have these two lemmas ever been proved? I would expect so, since they are not that hard to prove, and a particular case was used by my teacher to prove the monotone convergence theorem for abstract integrals. Have they? Do they have a name? Also, are these proofs valid? And is there any other suitable tag for this question?

**Edit:**
When I say I'd expect them to have been proved, I don't mean to say they are precious or anything. I'm merely saying, well, I'm not a super-mathematician, and I'm undergraduate, so if I proved them, some other more well-known person is bound to have observed this already. Just for clarity's sake.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? This looks like a perfectly fine question of whether a proof is valid or note. (Also, @OP, you could tag [tag:proof-verification])

Comment: The title is strange. I think that may explain the downvotes. It's also a little strange to ask whether an elementary lemma has a name. The vast majority of elementary results do not have names.

Comment: Have you checked out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior? I know your results aren't exactly that, but why do you expect them to be precious?

Comment: I don't really see how that page could relate to my lemmas, @RespawnedFluff, seen as all I can see there only deals with one sequence, one function, one set, or a sequence of sets related to which to find sets called liminf and limsup, whereas I am talking about a family of sequences of which to find the supremum of the limits or equivalently a sequence of families of which to find the limit of the supremums. All I see on that page (which I just gave a look at) has _one_ (or _zero_) index, while my results have _two_.

Comment: Besides, I don't expect them to be precious or anything, it's just a couple of things I found out and used on two occasions, so I wanted to know if they had already been found, since they weren't an exercise from a course, and if there was any name for them. That's all.

Comment: See the edit too.